# Matlab cell array with numbers as string and N/A present

Tags: matlab

I have a cell array which looks something like:

```
'0.86'
'0.07'
'N/A'
'1.3'
```

How do I process it to get a output as an array of doubles like:

```
0.86
0.07
0.0
1.3
```

I am stuck when I try to do something like:

```
cellfun(@str2num,Array);
```

As the str2num is not able to handle 'N/A' I guess.

Thanks

Comment: Where are you stuck at? Handling cell-arrays, converting strings to numbers, ...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are very close to the solution. Instead of using `str2num`, use `str2double`.

So,

```
Array ={'0.86', '0.07', 'N/A', '1.3'}
cellfun(@str2double,Array)
```

which outputs (as you requested):

```
ans =

    0.8600    0.0700       NaN    1.3000
```

Answer (score 4):

Use [`str2double`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html):

```
c = {'0.86'
     '0.07'
     'N/A'
     '1.3'};
result = str2double(c)
```

This gives

```
result =
    0.8600
    0.0700
       NaN
    1.3000
```

Comment: @mbschenkel Oh, I hadn't seen the other answer. Thanks